# Quando devo usar ModelState.IsValid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-validation

Quando devo usar o `ModelState.isValid`? É somente na inserção de dados? E no caso de `update` e `delete`? É preciso?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A verificação da validade do `ModelState` deve ser feita toda vez que um formulário é enviado. Não apenas para inserções, edições e exclusões.

O `ModelState` serve não apenas para *Models*, mas também para *ViewModels*. A função essencial de `ModelState` é representar a validade do que foi enviado para o *Controller* e, em caso de não validade, detalhar também os erros, se for o caso ([`ModelState.Errors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.errors(v=vs.118).aspx)).

Assim sendo, todo o trabalho de verificação do preenchimento e valores de cada propriedade do objeto enviado é feito sozinho. Você apenas precisa inserir a decoração apropriadamente no *Model* ou *ViewModel*.

Comment: Cigano, supondo que eu tenha tentado validar uma regra de negócio no backend e essa validação tenha falhado. O certo (ou mais comum) é adicionar a mensagem de erro no modelstate com ModelState.AddError? Hoje eu simplesmente lanço uma Exception e mostro ela num bootstrap alert...

Comment: `ModelState.AddModelError` é a maneira mais correta. Exceções são lentas e caracterizam falhas sistêmicas, não falhas de validação, que são fluxos previstos no funcionamento do sistema.